# Connection refused localhost with quarkus-reactive-pg-client

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

I have got a Quarkus app (security-web-authn-quickstart) with this pom configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.pjgg.webauthn</groupId>
  <artifactId>security-webauthn-demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.4.2</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven.home>~/.m2</maven.home>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-security-webauthn</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-security-webauthn</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

When I tried to start the application with
mvn compile quarkus:dev
It is supposed that the postgre SQL database start as a Dev Service and the app is up but with some WARN logs as :

```
HR000021: DDL command failed [io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:32769]
```

If I go to http://localhost:8080 and I try to register a new user to my db, the request will fail with a response error:

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: 
localhost/127.0.0.1:32769 
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

PW: Not sure if I should add some parameters to configure the PostgreSQL db on the applications.properties but with the given configuration in the quickstart example keep failing:

```
%prod.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
%prod.quarkus.datasource.username=quarkus
%prod.quarkus.datasource.password=quarkus
%prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql:elytron_security_webauthn

quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create

quarkus.webauthn.login-page=/
```

I have some questions here :

1. why quarkus-hibernate is trying to connect to port 32769 and is there any way to map to the correct port used by the docker image (5432)?
2. is needed to specify the port in the application.properties something like :
   `quarkus.datasource.url=vertx-reactive:postgresql://localhost:5432/quarkus_test`
3. Does That default properties configuration that is set %prod need to be overridden without '%prod' to be executed as a dev mod to get the configuration properly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, after the db is up an running with docker-compose up, it is needed run the correct command with the datasource URL,userand password like this:

```
mvn quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://localhost:5432/elytron_security_webauthn -Dquarkus.datasource.username=quarkus -Dquarkus.datasource.password=quarkus
```